# What are some visual representations of the lambda calculus?

Tags: lambda-calculus, education

I'm building some teaching tools for teaching the lambda calculus and would like some kind of visual representation of it. I've looked at [Alligator Eggs](http://worrydream.com/AlligatorEggs/) and while it is something very similar to what I'm looking for, I would like something that expresses church numerals in a more elegant way.

What other visual/graphical representations of the lambda calculus already exist?

Comment: Perhaps you'll get more replies on [cseducators.se].